# 'from gensim import test' is not importing successfully

Tags: python, python-3.4, gensim

I installed [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim), Python library.
I executed the command

```
Import gensim
```

It executed without any error. 
Then I tried to import test from gensim using the command

```
from gensim import test
```

and it showed the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>       from gensim import test
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'test'

Python site-packages had gensim folder in that. 
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: *“whatever I try to import”* – Well, `test` does not exist. Do things that actually exist work?

Comment: How is the question title related to the question itself?

Comment: I tried to update the question title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it says: `cannot import name 'test'`
That means that `test` is not in `gensim` package.

You can see package's modules with:

```
import gensim
print(gensim.__all__) # when package provide a __all__
```

or

```
import gensim
import pkgutil
modules = pkgutil.iter_modules(gensim.__path__)
for module in modules:
    print(module[1])
```

Edit:

> How can I verify gensim installation ?

```
try:
    import gensim
except NameError:
    print('gensim is not installed')
```

Side note: if you have a file or package named gensim, this will ne imported instead of the real package.

Comment: I tried this code and got another error.   NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined. Please suggest hoow can I verify gensim installation.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this and executed without print message.

Comment: `NameError: name 'gensim' is not defined` suggest that you tried without having `import gensim`. I split my example so there would be no misunderstanding.

Comment: Thank you @Cyrbil. I tried `try:
    import gensim
except NameError:
    print('gensim is not installed')
print('successful')
import pkgutil
modules = pkgutil.iter_modules(gensim.__path__)
for module in modules:
    print(module[1])` and the system generated message `modules = pkgutil.iter_modules(gensim.__path__)
AttributeError: module 'gensim' has no attribute '__path__''`

Comment: gensim has this information in its directory `dir(gensim)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__spec__', 'bz2', 'corpus', 'documents', 'gensim', 'logging']`

Comment: resolved. as there was another file with same name as package name. I deleted that and the problem resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar experience but with scipy. After uninstalling scipy  import scipy did not give error. but none of its modules will work. I noticed that scipy folder was still in \site-packages but modules inside it were uninstalled. 
When I installed it again it worked fine.
You should also see inside the directory, and try to reinstall or upgrade it.